# Magento2 : Call getViewFileUrl() function in block file

Tags: magento2, blocks, image, core

How to call function `getViewFileUrl()` in block file?

For `phtml` it is `$this->getViewFileUrl('images/img.jpg')` but it's not working on block file.

what is syntax for block file which class I have to inject ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository` class to get view file url in block file

```
protected $_assetRepo;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    ...
}
```

Now, you can get image URL by

```
echo $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Vendor_Module::images/img.jpg");
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what's your block file extends but generally block file `extends` [`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template.php#L31) and this class also extends [`AbstractBlock`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L24). and you can find [`getViewFileUrl()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L784) in this class. So If you are not using any custom feature on your block file then just extends this class(`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`) to take all benefit. And if you don't want to extend this class then [@Prince](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35758/prince-patel) already given your answer.

Comment: it was `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem`